# BufferedImage rotate and set with AffineTransform

Tags: java

I want to rotate and set a BufferedImage.Rotate operation is working with my code. However how can i set left margin and top margin

```
    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate(overlay.getWidth() / 2, overlay.getHeight() / 2);

    double d = Math.PI/2;
    at.rotate(d);
    at.translate(-overlay.getWidth()/2, -overlay.getHeight()/2);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.drawImage(overlay, at, null);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Rotate Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021150/java-rotate-image)

Comment: My problem is not rotation  g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); method is provide margin left and right px. g2d.drawImage(overlay, at, null); is not